# How to specify type for bulk list assignments

Tags: haskell, coding-style, warnings

I have the following code that looks like this

```
[a,b,c,d] = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

The compiler reports the warning:

```
Warning: Definition but no type signature for 'a'
         Inferred type: a :: [Char]
```

How to silence the warning and specify the type for this expression?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I don't get this problem in GHCi with 'let [a,b,c,d] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]'

Please post more details regarding the compiler (and its version).

Comment: ghc 6.10.4, not ghci.
Problem is when I do this assignment in the top level. If I move it inside method using let or where it doesn't report warning.
Ghc is set to use -Wall option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No errors in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let [a,b,c,d] = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

If you want to give the entire fragment a type, try,

```
   Prelude> let x :: [String]
                     x@[a,b,c,d] = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an explicit type signature for the variables:

```
a, b, c, d :: String
[a,b,c,d] = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

There should also be some compiler flag that disables the warning since it's common practice to not explicitly specify the types of every helper variable.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to avoid typing a,b,c,d twice.

Comment: You could probably just write [a,b,c,d] = ["a","b","c","d"] :: [String]